# Why is this Bokeh plot not showing up when embedded in Flask App?

Tags: python, flask, bokeh

I'm using Bokeh in a Python Flask app. In the `test_app.py` file have this code:

> [See the Code, data and output in iPython notebook...](https://github.com/RichardAfolabi/Sandbox-for-stuffs/blob/master/bokeh_flask_app.ipynb)

```
def make_figure():
     plot = figure(tools=TOOLS, width=750, height=450, title='United States Import/Exports',
              x_axis_label='date', x_axis_type='datetime')

     plot.line(dframe.index, dframe.get('Exports'), color='#A6CEE3', legend='Exports')
     return plot


@app.route('/')
def greet():
    greetings = 'Hello World, I am BOKEH'
    plot = make_figure()
    script, div = components(plot)

    return render_template('index.html', greetings=greetings, script=script, div=div)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In the `index.html` file, I have the following core part along with the required `js` and `css` links:

```
<body>
   <h1>{{ greetings | safe }} </h1>
    {{ script | safe }}
    {{ div | safe }}
</body>
```

Problem is, the Bokeh canvas, controls, etc show up but the line plot itself does not. What am I missing in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `dframe = dframe.set_index('Month')` and your good to go

[image]

Comment: might be worth reporting an issue on their https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh, setting an index name shouldn't remove the lines imho